# how to get a defautdict(set) like this form : {str : { str : int } }

Tags: python, dictionary

I got a  dictionary like this

```
{('a','b'):3, ('b','c'): 2, ('a','c'): 5}
```

I want to convert it to this form :

```
{'b': {'c': 2}, 'a': {'c': 5, 'b': 3}}
```

That means I have to build a dictionary like this form:

```
   d:{(str1,str2):int}   -->     {str1 : { str2 : int } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably do not want a `defaultdict` based on `set` but based on `dict` instead.

```
dic = {('a','b'):3, ('b','c'): 2, ('a','c'): 5}
dic2 = defaultdict(dict)
for j,k in dic:
    dic2[j][k] = dic[(j,k)]
## dic2 = defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'a': {'c': 5, 'b': 3}, 'b': {'c': 2}})
```

On a side note, `d.keys()` is already iterable, there is no need to call `list(d.keys())`. In fact, to iterate over the keys of a dictionary `d`, the best is to just call `for key in d:`

Comment: The question does not specify Python 2 or 3. `d.keys()` is **not** a list in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks @JohnY I did not know that ... i assume `for key in d:` is still preferred, right? ... I made a correction to my answer.

Comment: Right, to iterate over the keys, the best is `for key in d:`.

Answer (score 4):

How about this using `setdefault`:

```
d = {('a','b'):3, ('b','c'): 2, ('a','c'): 5}
out = {}
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    out.setdefault(k[0], {}).setdefault(k[1], v)

print out
```

### Output:

```
{'a': {'c': 5, 'b': 3}, 'b': {'c': 2}}
```

Comment: You don't need the second call to `setdefault`, since the keys will never be duplicated. Just use a regular dictionary assignment `out.setdefault(k[0], {})[k[1]] = v`. You can also unpack two parts of the key pair as part of the loop with `for (k1, k2), v in d.iteritems()`.